# How to do you get an array button to be side by side?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am new to Java as I tried to learn what I could within a week for a project for my class. I am creating a website through wordpress and the script works as I want it to..I can't move the buttons without messing something up and it no longer working. Right now they are stacked onto of each other but I would like them side by side

```
<button onclick="getThing()" type="button">Who?</button>
<button onclick="getArtStyle()" type="button">What?</button>

<div id="thing"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    var artArray = new Array("Poem", "Song", "Dance", "Drawing", "Story", "Painting",
        "Picture", "Play", "Bracelet", "Sign", "Joke", "Card", "Haiku", "Limerick", "Difference", "Doll", "Bathroom Graffiti", "Ghost Story", "Riddle", "Doodle", "Voodoo Doll", "Baked Good", "Replica");
    var thingArray = new Array("America", "Dad", "Mom", "Dog", "Dentist", "Parole Officer", "Cat", "Teacher", "Mailman", "Anyone", "Yourself", "Lover", "Professor", "Friend", "Frenemy", "Enemy", "Grandma", "Grandpa", "Somebody");

    function getArtStyle() {
        document.getElementById('answerDiv').innerHTML = artArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * artArray.length)];
    }

    function getThing() {
        document.getElementById('thing').innerHTML = thingArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * thingArray.length)];
    }
     // ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: `I am new to Java` The first thing you have to realize is that this is not Java.

Comment: Where is 'answerDiv' here

Comment: @PellePenna That is not the right way to correct the question.  OP has a small misunderstanding between Java ans JS.  Derek approach of adding comments is the right way.

Comment: @Praveen: Approach how edit the post maybe, but by writing "have to realize it is not Java" is to assume the OP don't know the difference, which I think one shouldn't. "To ask" if OP knows, is a more proper and polite way.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<style>
    #thing, #answerDiv {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```

if it fails, try this:

```
<style>
    #thing, #answerDiv {
        float: left;
        clear: none;
    }
</style>
```

**EDIT:** This assumes when you say "they are stacked on top of each other" you are referring to the resulting `<div>`s and not the buttons.  Otherwise replace `#thing, #answerDiv` with `button`.

Your WordPress theme probably has them floating with a clear or (if in the case of the buttons) displayed as blocks (which adds a new line before/after).